# Linux: network inteface tunneling include states

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, port, tunneling

I would like to implement network interfaces tunneling between two machines. I also need to synchronize the network interfaces states:

```
Machine A:                         Machine B
---------------------------------------------
eth22 [UP]    <---------------->   eth22 [UP]
eth23 [UP]    <---------------->   eth23 [UP]
eth24 [DOWN]  <---------------->   eth24 [DOWN]
```

The tunnel should forward everything from Machine A to B and vice versa (all protocols, i.e. it should work on Level 2).
As well, when a network interface of Machine A is down, the related network interface on Machine B as well down (but it always exists).
I need it to mimics all network interfaces of Machine A on Machine B.
There are enough tunnels in Linux; however, I don't know how to manage network interface states.